# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4e9544fc0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**This is the code that I tried running on Xcode and the idea is when I press the button, it will show the background and the logo, however when I press the button, it just leads me straight into the error**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var coolLogo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var coolBg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var uncoolButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func makeMeNotSoUncoolButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    coolLogo.hidden = false
    coolBg.hidden = false
    uncoolButton.hidden = true
    print ("Its running")
}

}
```

**This is the error that I got**

```
2016-06-29 10:19:01.229 SuperCool[1950:40240] -

[SuperCool.ViewController uncoolButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4e9544fc0
2016-06-29 10:19:01.238 SuperCool[1950:40240] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SuperCool.ViewController uncoolButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4e9544fc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f617d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001113bbdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f620d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f566cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5668a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010fe41a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ffb4e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010ffb5143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ffb4263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010feb499f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010feb56d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010fe60dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fe3a553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f53d301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f53322c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5326e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5320f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113cadad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010fe3ff09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  SuperCool                           0x000000010f432422 main + 114
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111e7f92d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you connected either the `uncoolButton` outlet or the `makeMeNotSoUncoolButton` action incorrectly.

Comment: How to fix: try reconnecting the button to the outlet/action

Comment: problem solved! I tried deleting the outlet and the action, it still has the same problem. I guess somehow I might have wrongly connected it and it's saved some where else. 

So what I did was I recreate a new project and carefully assign the right type, and it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just place brakepoint in that method and check your `self` class and class of your button, than you will know what isn't as you expected. You can check class using method `class`, that returns instance of your clas, than just print it to log.

Comment: I bet it never calls that function.

Comment: No -- I'm not the author -- I just think it's hooked up wrong and never gets called.  If the author put a breakpoint there and it actually hits it, then I'd recheck the outlets.

Comment: Oh, you are supposing that author set outlet in views file and do not create the same in his controller? Yeh, that as well may be the reason. Than he needs to recheck his views file or just remove all outlets and make them again.